# How to add options to select field from php array to Contact form 7 Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have an one-page site in wordpress. I need to put information from php array $cat_good in two select box. It works ok in index.php file like this:

```
<div>
    <select id="flowers_type" class="styled">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <?php 
            foreach ( $cat_good as $key => $value) {
                echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $key . '</option>';
            } 
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select id="flowers_type_item" class="styled">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <?php 
            foreach ( $cat_good as $key => $value) {
                $good = $key;
                foreach ( $value as $key => $value ) {
                    echo '<option class="' . $good . '" value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>'; 
                }
            } 
        ?> 
    </select>
</div>
```

The question is, how to put these two select box to contact form 7?

With help of Dhanuka Nuwan now I have the code in function.php, which helps me to add selectors to contact form 7.

```
function flowers_type(){<!-- here is my code for $cat_good -->
$output .= "<div><select name='flowers_type' id='flowers_1' class='styled'><option value='0'>--</option>";      
    foreach ( $cat_good as $key => $value) {
        $output .= "<option value='$key'>$key</option>";         
     }
$output .= "</select></div>";
$output .= "<div><select name='flowers_type_item' id='flowers_2' class='styled'><option value='0'>--</option>";     
    foreach ( $cat_good as $key => $value) {
        $good = $key;
        foreach ( $value as $key => $value ) {
            $output .= "<option class='$good' value='$key'>$value</option>";
        }
     }
     $output .= "</select></div>";
     return $output;}
```

But also I need the second selector to be depended from the first. I'm trying to do this with help https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained. In my js file I have:

```
$("#flowers_2").chained("#flowers_1");
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is your form you want to add select ?

Comment: In file index.php a have a shortcode <?php echo do_shortcode ('[contact-form-7 id="53" title="..."]');?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a shortcode to contact form 7 using `wpcf7_add_shortcode` easily. Here is your code.

```
function flowers_type(){
   $output = "<select name='flowers_type' id='flowers_type' onchange='document.getElementById(\"flowers_type\").value=this.value;'><option value="">--</option>";
   foreach ( $cat_good as $key => $value) {
            $output .= "<option value='$key'> $key </option>";
        } 

   $output .= "</select>";
return $output;
}

wpcf7_add_shortcode('flowers_type', 'flowers_type', true);
```

now you can use [flowers_type] shortcode inside your contact form 7 form.Please note this code is not tested. backup your files before use. do the same thing to your other one.

Have fun.  :)

Comment: @AnaSkalabava glad to help you. if you mind please give me an upvote aswell  :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation for this. I'll give you upvote for sure, when I can.

Comment: The second selector should be depended from the value chosen in the first. Out of the contact form 7 with help https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained, this was ok. But now it's doen't work.

Comment: what did you tried? can you post a code? That'll be helpful for me to give you an answer

Comment: A gonna post it in post above.

Comment: sorry. I was away. just came home. What do you really mean by "second selector to be depended from the first". What are you rying to do ? Can you eplain to me ?

Comment: I need to make this effect http://jsfiddle.net/pamjaranka/t3oktx9o/4/ As you see, here it's work well. But somehow within contact form 7 it's broken.

Comment: Try replacing jquery $ sign to jQuery. like this `jQuery('.flower_1').val();`

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the `<option value="">` in the 2nd line uses the wrong quotes for this to work.